# Reformatting json file

Tags: python, data-science

I'm trying to reformat a JSON file so I can convert it into a Python dictionary. The file contains line-separated JSON objects with different product info (looks like this):

```
{"asin": "7301113188", "category": ["Appliances", "Refrigerators, Freezers & Ice Makers"], "description": [], "fit": "", "title": "Tupperware Freezer Square Round Container Set of 6", "also_buy": [], "image": [], "tech2": "", "brand": "Tupperware", "feature": ["Each 3-pc. set includes two 7/8-cup/200 mL and one 1-3/4-cup/400 mL.", "Use them to keep sandwich fillings, salads or leftovers fresh in the refrigerator.", "Gently twist the container to \"pop\" out frozen foods for reheating.", "Dishwasher Safe.", "Set weights less than 13 oz!"], "rank": [">#39,745 in Appliances (See top 100)"], "also_view": [], "details": {}, "main_cat": "Appliances", "similar_item": "", "date": "November 19, 2008", "price": ""}
{"asin": "7861850250", "category": ["Appliances", "Refrigerators, Freezers & Ice Makers"], "tech2": "", "brand": "Tupperware", "feature": ["2 X Tupperware Pure & Fresh Unique Covered Cool Cubes Ice Tray in Purple With Opening Lid Contain 14 Cubes - HerbalStore_24*7", "Package Contain :- 2 Tray", "Each ice tray has a specially designed seal that allows you to fill from the faucet with no spills on the way to the freezer. While freezing, this seal helps keep flavor in and freezer odors out, ensuring you have pure ice every time. For something special, try freezing lemonade, tea or fruit juices in these Ice Tray to give your beverages an extra-flavorful kick. Or add a piece of fruit to each cube for a stylish touch of elegance.", "Sold By:- HerbalStore_24*7", "Free Shipping"], "rank": [">#6,118 in Appliances (See top 100)"], "also_view": ["B004RUGHJW"], "details": {}, "main_cat": "Appliances", "similar_item": "", "date": "June 5, 2016", "price": "$3.62"}
```

I want the dict to contain key-pair values where each "asin" is a key and the rest of the product info is a value. What's the most optimal way to do this?

Comment: You should start with a possibly sub-optimal attempt, and come back here with any specific problems doing that. If you have something working, then codereview.stackexchange.com would be more appropriate for gathering feedback on improvements.

Comment: Why does it have to be optimal? Best to get something sub-optimal working first and then improve it if necessary. What have you done so far? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: As is, you can start by simply iterating over this line-by-line: `dicts = [json.loads(x) for x in f]` (where `f` is a file handle opened using a `with` statement).

Answer (score -1):

You can parse JSON dictionaries using [**`json.loads`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

```
import json

final = {}

for line in lines:
    d = json.loads(line)
    final[d['asin']] = d
    del d['asin']
```

It's also possible to parse some JSON-like text using [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). The JSON-like text has to not have any boolean or null values, as is the case with your example. Below is the changes needed:

```
from ast import literal_eval

...
    d = literal_eval(line)
    ...
```

Comment: Not all JSON is valid Python. `ast.literal_eval()` should only be used for Python literals, not JSON.

Comment: (For example, JSON uses `true` and `false` for booleans, but those keywords aren't valid in Python -- they'd need to be `True` and `False` for `ast.literal_eval()` to work).

Comment: Same for `null` and `None`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll update to note. However, the example is only dictionaries with strings and lists of strings.